# How to concatenate strings with binary values in python?

Tags: python, string, binary, concatenation

What's the easiest way in python to concatenate string with binary values ?

```
sep = 0x1
data = ["abc","def","ghi","jkl"]
```

Looking for result data `"abc0x1def0x1ghi0x1jkl"` with the 0x1 being binary value not string "0x1".

Comment: No binary values there. 0x1 is hexadecimal; 0b1 would be binary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think

```
joined = '\x01'.join(data)
```

should do it. `\x01` is the escape sequence for a byte with value 0x01.

Comment: +1 Great thanks, I tried similar thing but did not think about escaping the characters to create a 'character' ...

Comment: Works great: 8=10^A9=ABC^A10=BBB^A34=D

Comment: @pdc : This [doesn’t work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33242721/2284570) with mmap.

Answer (score 4):

The chr() function will have the effect of translating a variable into a string with the binary value you are looking for.

```
>>> sep = 0x1
>>> sepc = chr(sep)
>>> sepc
'\x01'
```

The join() function can then be used to concat a series of strings with your binary value as a separator.

```
>>> data = ['abc']*3
>>> data
['abc', 'abc', 'abc']
>>> sepc.join(data)
'abc\x01abc\x01abc'
```

Comment: @ricree : This [doesn’t work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33242721/2284570) with mmap.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the best method, but another way that could be useful in different context for the same question is:

```
>>> x=(str(bin(0b110011000)))
>>> b=(str(bin(0b11111111111)))
>>> print(x+b)
0b1100110000b11111111111
```

And if needed, to remove the left-most two bits of each string (i.e. 0b pad) the slice function `[2:]` with a value of 2 works:

```
>>> x=(str(bin(0b110011000)[2:]))
>>> b=(str(bin(0b11111111111)[2:]))
>>> print(x+b)
11001100011111111111
```